# Function to create 24h periods timestamps? c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have database where data is stored along timestamp entries, that are keys.

i need a function that can transform a date like DateTime.Now into a timestamp interval representing, for today as example, Aug 30th 00:00:00h to Aug 30th 23:59:59h.

How could i write that function?

What i want is to do something like

select all from table where timestamp is between a and b.(those and b values would represent the initial and terminal timestamps for a day.)

I did not create the db, i cannot modify it, i can only query it.

Comment: By looking in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Use [DateTime.Today, DateTime.Today.AddDays(1).AddMilliseconds(-1)]

Comment: A little offtopic, but using timestamps for keys is likely to be a very bad idea.

Comment: @Zruty using `.Today` twice in a row is dangerous at nearly-midnight

Comment: And easily avoided with DateTime.Date

Comment: Small note; personally I'd avoid the whole `AddTicks(-1)` / `AddMilliseconds(-1)` etc; instead, when I'm working on a day range I simply store the days. Then compare `start <= x < end` - i.e. inclusive on the left, exclusive on the right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will return a tuple representing the interval you probably want:

```
Tuple<DateTime,DateTime> GetDateInterval(DateTime datetime) {
    var start = datetime.Date;
    var end = start.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
    return new Tuple<DateTime, DateTime>(start, end);
}
```

Usage:

```
var interval = GetDateInterval(DateTime.Now);
Console.WriteLine(interval.Item1);
Console.WriteLine(interval.Item2);
```

Output:

```
30.08.2011 0:00:00
30.08.2011 23:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay.Ticks` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell what you want, but here is a way to get the interval:

```
var start = DateTime.Today;
var end = start.AddDays(1).AddSeconds(-1);
```

It's hard to answer how you should store the values in the DB since you haven't provided enough details about the table layout.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might try using a structure as a TimeInterval:

```
public struct TimeInterval
{
    private readonly DateTime _startTime;
    private readonly DateTime _endTime;

    public DateTime StartTime { get { return _startTime; } }
    public DateTime EndTime { get { return _endTime; } }

    public TimeInterval(DateTime now)
    {
        _startTime = now.Date;
        _endTime = now.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1);
    }
}
```

You can call it:

```
TimeInterval day = new TimeInterval(DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the scope of a day, you can calculate the ticks withing the day:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public long GetTicksOfDay( DateTime moment )
{
  return moment.Subtract( moment.Date ).Ticks;
} // GetTicksOfDay
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is a [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx).

You can just substract one DateTime from another, and the result will be a TimeSpan of the difference.

Comment: But the result will only have the difference between two dates, which is known to be 24h beforehand, which makes this function kinda useless